# Copy data depending on parameter

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2014

I'm having a total blackout right now and hope someone could help me. In my application users are able to copy data from one table to another by clicking on buttons. The data from source table is being retrieved differently, depending on the page where the user clicks on a copy button.

**My tables**

*tabPlanning*

```
+--------------+-------------+--------+--------+--------------+
|  PlanningId  |  RequestId  | Field1 | Field2 |    Field3    |
|--------------|-------------|--------|--------|--------------|
| Primary key  | Foreign key |        |        |              |
+--------------+-------------+--------+--------+--------------+
|      INT     |     INT     |  DATE  | BIGINT | NVARCHAR(20) |
+--------------+-------------+--------+--------+--------------+
```

*tabPlanningCopy*

```
+------------------+-------------+--------+--------+--------------+
|  PlanningCopyId  |  RequestId  | Field1 | Field2 |    Field3    |
|------------------|-------------|--------|--------|--------------|
|   Primary Key    | Foreign Key |        |        |              |
+------------------+-------------+--------+--------+--------------+
|        INT       |     INT     |  DATE  | BIGINT | NVARCHAR(20) |
+------------------+-------------+--------+--------+--------------+
```

**My stored procedure**

*spCopyPlanning*

`spCopyPlanning` copies data from `tabPlanning` to `tabPlanningCopy` depending on parameters:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.spCopyPlanning
    @PlanningId INT = NULL
    @RequestId INT = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    IF @PlanningId IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tabPlanning WHERE RequestId = @RequestId)
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO tabPlanningCopy(RequestId, Field1, Field2, Field3)
            SELECT RequestId,
                Field1,
                Field2,
                Field3
            FROM tabPlanning
            WHERE PlanningId = @PlanningId
        END
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tabPlanning WHERE RequestId = @RequestId)
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO tabPlanningCopy(RequestId, Field1, Field2, Field3)
            SELECT RequestId,
                Field1,
                Field2,
                Field3
            FROM tabPlanning
            WHERE RequestId = @RequestId
        END
    END
END

-- @PlanningId IS NOT NULL -> copy the row with PlanningId = @PlanningId

-- @PlanningId IS NULL -> copy the row with RequestId = @RequestId
```

The procedure is working as it is written right now. However, I don't think this is the nicest approach to get what I want (I hate redundancy!). I'm pretty sure it can be achieved by expanding the `WHERE` statement but I don't have any clue right now how to solve this. Could anyone lead me to a solution to get rid of my redundant code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is redundant because everything but the WHERE clause is identical except where it evaluates whether or not a parameter is null. As parameters are or are not null, it's a simple matter of specifying two pairs of conditions in the Where. Try the following:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.spCopyPlanning
    @PlanningId INT = NULL
    @RequestId INT = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tabPlanning WHERE RequestId = @RequestId)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO tabPlanningCopy(RequestId, Field1, Field2, Field3)
        SELECT RequestId,
            Field1,
            Field2,
            Field3
    FROM tabPlanning
    WHERE (@PlanningId is not null
            and PlanningId = @PlanningId)
        or (@PlanningId is null
            and RequestId = @RequestId)
    END
END
```